# SQL selecting distinct values from set of values in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have the following table as a result of my query :

```
value1     name  
------     ------
 abc       JOHN
 def       JOHN
 mno       JOHN
 mno       JOHN
 abc       JAMES
 abc       JAMES
 def       JAMES
 mno       RICK
```

In the above table the value mno is repeated twice for `JOHN` and value `abc` is repeated twice for `JAMES`.

The query I used is here :

```
SELECT tc.value, tr.name
  FROM table1 tc, table2 tr
 WHERE tc.id = tr.roll
 ORDER BY tr.name;
```

The result i would like to expect is that the duplicate values has to be removed from each name. 
Result should be something like this:

```
value1   name
------  ------
 abc     JOHN
 def     JOHN
 mno     JOHN
 abc     JAMES
 def     JAMES
 mno     RICK
```

I Just want to remove the duplicate value from each name.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 5):

Try with distinct as below and also please use standard joining as shown.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tc.value, tr.name 
FROM table1 tc 
INNER JOIN table2 tr 
ON tc.id = tr.roll 
ORDER BY tr.name;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DISTINCT` keyword as you already tagged :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.value, t2.name
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.roll
 ORDER BY t2.name;
```

or `GROUP BY t1.value, t2.name` clause,  alternatively  :

```
SELECT t1.value, t2.name
  FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.roll
 GROUP BY t1.value, t2.name   
 ORDER BY t2.name;
```